# BufferedReader readLine() from standard input

Tags: java

I need to read from the standard input. I am not that familiar with BufferedReader and have only used Scanner so far. Scanner (or probably something inside my code) keeps on giving me TLE. Now the problem is that BufferedReader seems to skip some lines and I keep on getting a NumberFormatException.

Here's my code:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    int cases = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

    for(int i = 0; i < cases && cases <= 10; i++) {
        int numLines = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        String[] lines = new String[numLines + 1];
        HashSet<String> pat = new HashSet<String>();

        for(int j = 0; j < numLines && j <= 10; j++) {
            String l = reader.readLine();

            String patternStr = "\\W+";
            String replaceStr = "";

            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr);
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(l.toString());

            String m = matcher.replaceAll(replaceStr);

            lines[j] = m;
            getPatterns(m, pat);

            System.out.println(m);
        }
```

The error occurs after the second input. Please help.

Comment: Any readon, why you are using BufferedReader instead of Scanner?

Comment: `reader.readLine().trim()` when you parse to Integer

Comment: normally you have to read from `BufferedReader` in a loop until `null`

Comment: @RohitJain `BufferedReader` is faster than `Scanner`. [From the official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html): "Without buffering, each invocation of read() or readLine() could cause bytes to be read from the file, converted into characters, and then returned, which can be very inefficient."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`BufferedReader#readLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) method does not read the newline character at the end of the line. So, when you call `readLine()` twice, the first one will read your input, and the second one will read the `newline` left over by the first one.

That is why it is skipping the input you gave.

You can use [`BufferedReader#skip()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#skip%28long%29) to skip the newline character after every `readLine` in your `for loop`.