# How can I implement the following code below using the BufferedReader?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

This code is for implementing the game of craps.  I have tested all my other code with this program and it works just fine.  At first, I had the following block of code below in my Driver working via a Scanner object, but my professor told me I had to use BufferedReader.

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Driver
{
    /*
    Dan Czarnecki
    October 8, 2013

    Class variables:
    n/a

    Constuctors:
    n/a

    Methods:
        public static void main(String[] args)
            Calls the necessary methods in the Craps class to simulate the game of craps

    Modification history:
        October 1, 2013
            Original program

        October 8, 2013
            Fixed style issues

        October 20, 2013
            Fixed more style issues
            Final version of program
    */

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BufferedReader br;
        InputStreamReader isr;
        br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        int play;
        System.out.println("Would you like to play craps? (1 for yes, 0 for no)");

        play = br.nextInt();

        if(play == 1)
        {
            Craps cr;
            cr = new Craps();
            System.out.println("The value of the roll is: " + cr.roll());
        while(cr.gameOver() == false);

            cr.roll();

        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("See you later!");
        }

    }
}
```

I know that the current way I have it re-implemented using BufferedReader is wrong, so could someone tell me how I'm actually supposed to implement it?

Comment: You should initialize `isr` before initializing your buffered reader on it.

Comment: Ok. So when I initialize the InputStreamReader, do I also initialize it with the variable that I was using before when I was using Scanner?

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13966448/bufferedreader-readline-from-standard-input : `BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What an odd requirement. Scanner was invented exactly for this sort of thing.

However, now you can only use the readLine() method of BufferedReader and you'll need to convert the String to whatever datatype you're trying to get (ints, etc.).

Comment: I know, right?  I don't get why my professor isn't allowing me to use Scanner in this case.  BufferedReader is more suitable for reading files, but I don't get why he would want me to use that instead of Scanner.